# Сорри, переписать axios => fetch

Tags: axios, fetch

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

import Cryptocurrency from './Crypto2';

class Ticker extends Component {

    fetchCryptocurrencyData() {
        axios.get('https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/tickers', {
            method: 'HEAD',
            mode: 'no-cors',
            headers: { 
                'x-apikey': 'qwTOFqqg4Z3IzXIcwUTbzSgWSx7sAtn3WF1YENaSako',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
              } 
        })
            .then(response => {
                var wanted = ["BTCUSD", "ETHUSD", "XRPUSD", "BCHUSD", "LTCUSD", "NEOUSD"];
                var result = response.data.filter(currency => wanted.includes(currency.pair));
                this.setState({data: result});    
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchCryptocurrencyData();
        this.interval = setInterval(() => this.fetchCryptocurrencyData(), 60000);
    }
    state = {
        data: [
            {   
                pair: "BTCUSD",
                bid: ""
            },
            {
                pair: "ETHUSD",
                bid: ""
            },
            {
                pair: "XRPUSD",
                bid: ""
            },
            {
                pair: "BCHUSD",
                bid: ""
            },
            {
                pair: "LTCUSD",
                bid: ""
            },
            {
                pair: "NEOUSD",
                bid: ""
            }
        ]
    }
    render() {
        var tickers = this.state.data.map((currency) => 
        <Cryptocurrency data={currency} key={currency.pair}/>
        )
        return(
            <div className="tickers-container">
                <div className='tickers'> {tickers} </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
      }
}

export default Ticker;
```

Проблема: хочу воспользоваться githubpages, cors не пропускает, нужно переписать запрос под fetch, помогите.

Comment: А что именно вы хотите получить в качестве ответа?

Comment: Добрый день, помогите с кодом, мне нужно получить данные с сервера, но я уже запутался, ошибка "TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined", какие данные нужно передать в result?

Comment: т.е. код должен искать сравнение с массивом wanted, и и выводить данные в результат

Comment: Пожалуйста укажите это все в самом вопросе

Comment: очевидно `data` - undefined

Comment: Вам там не `this.state.data` нужен (вместо `this.data`)?